# Do Zacian and Zamazenta have Steel Beam in their Crowned Form tutor set, like all other Steel-Type Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I was just posting a comment about the move Steel Beam when I wondered: If you had a Zacian or Zamazenta in their Crowned forms outside of battle, could it learn Steel Beam?

First, I want to talk about Zacian and Zamazenta's Crowned forms. These forms are only used in battle and add the Steel Type to the legendary dogs, sort of like Groudon and Kyogre's Primal forms (but without that long opening animation that plays the first time they are sent into battle).

This is why I wondered: Because Zacian and Zamazenta gain the Steel Type when they are in their Crowned forms, what if they could be in these forms outside of battle? And if they can, could they learn Steel Beam like any other Steel type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Steel_Beam_(move)), Zacian and Zamazenta can learn Steel Beam. Despite their Steel type being conditional, their form is irrelevant in this case

> A Move Tutor will teach Steel Beam to any Steel-type Pokémon (except for Dusk Mane Necrozma), **as well as both Zacian and Zamazenta**. Arceus and Silvally can also learn the move regardless of their current type

Comment: So according to that paragraph from Bulbapedia, they think Dusk Mane Necrosma isn't a Steel-type, yet scroll down to the learnset and you see NDM (**N**ecrozma **D**usk **M**ane) is listed as a Steel/Psychic-type. Also thank you for answering, this has been a topic I was wondering about for a long time (reappeared recently).